# Почему Неправильно считает сумму чисел?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a, b, c;
        int SumNumber = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Введите число a");
        a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите число b");
        b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите число c");
        c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (a > 0)
            SumNumber = SumNumber + a;
        if (b > 0)
            SumNumber = SumNumber + a;
        if (c > 0)
            SumNumber = SumNumber + a;



        Console.WriteLine("Сумма положительных чисел = "+ SumNumber); // +  добавить ту переменную которая считала + числа

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы `a` прибавляете всегда.

Comment: "Почему Не правильно считает" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: А за что минусят? За то что вопрос от новичка, который может еще код даже читать не привык? Обратите внимание, многие на SO даже код в вопрос не могут нормально вставить, а здесь даже выглядит вменяемо.

Comment: @aepot Наверно за то, что этот вопрос бесполезен для базы "вопрос-ответ" и вызван он опечаткой, для чего даже есть специальная "закрывашка", которая гласит: `Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации вопроса.`. Сам же автор не стал разбираться сам и первым дело пошёл строчить вопрос. P.S. Минус не мой.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ок, справедливо. Но одно дело закрывашка, другое дело невнятный или криво оформленный вопрос, "на который невозможно дать объективный ответ".

Comment: @aepot Ну я тут не вижу внятного вопроса, которых хорошо оформлен, что бы давать ему ответ. Я вижу кусок кода, не более, без объяснений, без рассуждений автора почему так. Этот вопрос можно переформулировать даже как "Вот вам код, найдите ошибку в нем, мне лень". И вот мы уже с вами нашли 2-ю проблему, почему этому вопросу могут дать минус. Короче дальше я не вижу смысла это обсуждать тут, комментарии не для этого. Вопрос следует закрыть, а не отвечать, ибо ему не место в базе вопросов. Я проголосовал, чего и вам советую.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да уже проголосовал, я не против.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внимательнее надо быть.

```csharp
if (a > 0)
    SumNumber = SumNumber + a;
if (b > 0)
    SumNumber = SumNumber + b;
if (c > 0)
    SumNumber = SumNumber + c;
```